# Load folder name as column in delta table

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

```
/SRC1/trialbucket=1/1.parquet
/SRC1/trialbucket=2/2.parquet
/SRC2/trialbucket=1/3.parquet
/SRC2/trialbucket=2/4.parquet
```

All the above parquet files in the folders have the same schema.

eg. `Col1,Col2,Col3`

I have to load all the files into a delta table with the following schema

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Source

data1,data2,data3,SRC1

data11,data22,data33,SRC1
data1111,data222,data333,SRC1
data5,data6,data7,SRC2
data55,data66,data77,SRC2
data555,data666,data777,SRC2
```

I can do it with each and add the folder name as the last column (`.withColumn`) but I have to go through 10000 such folders to read all the parquet files and load them into a table which takes a lot of time!

Is there any other way without the for loop to get the folder name and add it to the column?

Comment: [input_file_name](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) may be helpful

Comment: input file name can be anything. The column would be the folder name (SRC1 or SRC2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `regexp_extract` to get the foot folder name from the `input_file_name` :

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("Source", regexp_extract(input_file_name(), "/(.*)/.*", 1))
```

Comment: this works fine for small number of folders. but not efficient for reading through 10000 folders and loading all the parquet data into a delta table!

Comment: @justanothertekguy maybe you can load the folders per batch and insert into the same delta table at each iteration.

Comment: how would i load them in batch?

Comment: @justanothertekguy by iterating over a list of folders or some pattern that you can use to construct the folder paths, then in each iteration you load a small set of folders and insert into your table .. this might be a new question though.